# Копирование чужого дизайна

Tags: авторские-права

Мне очень понравился дизайн редактора статей vk. Я собираюсь сделать на сайте раздел, в котором можно добавлять статьи, с таким интерфейсом как у vk

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Могут ли у меня быть проблемы из-за копирования?

Answer (score 0):

Учитывая, что редактор статей вк с*****н с телеграфа - вряд-ли. Да и не станет никто патентовать просто набор шрифтов и расположение элементов.

Comment: шрифты запатентованы и если это вскроется на каком-нибудь сайте (особенно если сайт принадлежит какой-нибудь компании) могут быть серьезные проблемы; поэтому все ищут какой-нибудь бесплатный шрифт или его бесплатный аналог.

Comment: @Leks а если я использую другой шрифт, а расположение элементов останется таким же, то впринципе, это нормально?

Comment: @Михаил Камахин не знаю извините что не могу помочь ...

Comment: @Gohryt  вот нашел статью в интернете можете поискать и другие если стало интересно http://intelight.pro/narushenije-prava-na-shrift/

Comment: @МихаилКамахин на счет таких предметов как дизайн, искусство и прочие подобные элементы интеллектуальной  собственности, можете сильно не париться, это слишком сложно доказать в суде, да и никто не будет браться за это, тем более в РФ, у нас патентное законодательство... его как бы и нет, да и патент на дизайн это тоже так себе, достаточно что-то подвинуть или изменить = переработать, а это уже станет вашем предметом интеллектуальной  собственности

Comment: Ох уж эти минусаторы (@Leks) на пустом месте . Бесспорно шрифты являются объектом авторского права, только вот вк использует Roboto, свободно-распростроняемый шрифт от гугла, который можно использовать где угодно.

Comment: @Gohryt по вашему ответу было это неясно и минус не я поставил если вдруг подумали ...